# NUnit test for Xamarin.Forms ListViews with cell binding

Tags: listview, xamarin, view, xamarin.forms, nunit

I'm trying to write unit tests for a `ListView` with a custom `DataTemplate`. Although the cells are rendered as expected on iOS and Android, their bound properties are `null` when running NUnit tests.

**The setup**

To initiate Xamarin.Forms in an NUnit test project, I'm using [Xamarin.Forms.Mocks](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/Xamarin.Forms.Mocks). So the `TestFixture` looks as follows:

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Mocks;

namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            MockForms.Init();
        }
```

**What works**

One test, which is working well, creates a new `DataTemplate` with a custom `StringCell` bound to a string "foo":

```cs
        class StringCell : ViewCell
        {
            public StringCell()
            {
                var label = new Label();
                label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
                View = label;
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void ViewCellWithString()
        {
            var content = new DataTemplate(typeof(StringCell)).CreateContent();
            (content as Cell).BindingContext = "foo";

            Assert.That(((content as ViewCell).View as Label).Text, Is.EqualTo("foo"));
        }
```

As expected, the rendered `content` is a `ViewCell` with a `View` of type `Label` with the `Text` "foo".

**What doesn't work**

A second test, however, fails: It creates a `DataTemplate` of type `ItemCell` bound to a custom object `Item` with a bindable property `Name` "bar".

```cs
        class Item : BindableObject
        {
            public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Name), typeof(string), typeof(Item), null);

            public string Name {
                get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
                set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
            }
        }

        class ItemCell : ViewCell
        {
            public ItemCell()
            {
                var label = new Label();
                label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Item.NameProperty));
                View = label;
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void ViewCellWithItem()
        {
            var content = new DataTemplate(typeof(ItemCell)).CreateContent();
            (content as Cell).BindingContext = new Item { Name = "bar" };

            Assert.That(((content as ViewCell).View as Label).Text, Is.EqualTo("bar"));
        }
```

This test fails, because the Label's `Text` property is `null`.

**My question**

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the binding to a string via `"."` behave similar to the binding to an `Item` via `NameProperty`? Or is there a better way to instantiate the view of a list view cell with binding properties for unit testing purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the tiny but crucial mistake in my code:

Instead of

```
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Item.NameProperty));
```

I need to write

```
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Item.Name));
```

since `nameof(Item.NameProperty)` yields "NameProperty", but I need to bind to "Name".